# JSF 2 : panelGrid questions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

1) I can see that panelGrid has an attribute of footerClass, headerClass.How can i specify the footer and header contents, i guess via facets ?

2) And this leads to another question :

> How can i know if a jsf tag has facets or support any other nested tags ?

I know panelGrid support nested h:panelGroup, but i wonder what other nested tags are supported inside panelGrid tag ?

3) And basing on the attributes reference im having, i suppose cell merging (colspan) is not supported, am i correct ?

4) Is panelGrid replaceable by plain html table ? I suppose panelGrid really eases us without all the tr and td tags, eases us in even / odd rows / columns css class specification, etc. But if i want to have fuller control of the table, like the width of each column, cell merging, i'd have to switch to HTML table, am i correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your questions are covered by the tag library [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGrid.html) which covers the supported facets and attributes. The behaviour of the control is largely fixed - if this isn't what you want, don't use it.

> How can I know if a JSF tag has facets or support any other nested tags?

Supported facets and children should be listed in the documentation. A `panelGrid` can contain pretty much any control (within the restrictions of the markup generated by the rendered page).

Comment: Thank you. The doc indeed lists the facets. But as for the nested tags, i dont see. For example, in the panelGrid doc, i dont see it mention any panelGroup as it's possible nested tag. But as you said, it can contain any control, and that's too general to be listed there. Thanks again ! =)